# Click event is not firing using getElementByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a navigation link the structure is like this . I have a requirement in which I have to get the element by innerHTML instead of id.

```
<li>
   <a id="someID">Products</a>
</li>
```

When I am using `document.getElementById()` and attaching a click event to it click event is firing.
But now I want to get the element by innerHTML.
So I did this:

```
 var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for(var i=0;i<anchors.length;i++){
console.log(anchors[i].innerHTML)
if(anchors[i].innerHTML == 'Products'){
console.log("coming here");
var menuButton = anchors[i].parentElement
console.log(menuButton)
break;

}

}
console.log(menuButton instanceof HTMLElement);
menuButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert("hello");
  });
```

But in this click event is not firing ?

Comment: menuButton.addEventListener is out of for loop. Can u try put it inside for loop ?

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other a tags. I tried the above code, it worked!

Comment: yes I have tried putting it inside loop still it wont work , it is a simple set up you can create it on your end and do let me know if you find a solution

Answer (score 1):

The Incorrect manner your trying to obtain the element in `<a>`, the condition obviously ignores if you assign `[object HTMLCollection]  == 'Products'`

```
var anchors = document.getElementById("someID").value;
```

or if you need to obtain the value using specific tag,

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML
```

Comment: it doesn't I made it sure by console.logs it is getting correct element

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
if(<HTMLInputElement>anchors[i].innerHTML == 'Products'){
    console.log("coming here");
    var menuButton = anchors[i].parentElement
    console.log(menuButton)
    break;
    
    }
```